# Laravel - prevent POST method spamming

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

so I got a button on my site with method equal to `POST`. Some users spam-click the button and make many controller function calls in 1 second, which messes up the checks within my controller function. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Multiple Submitting in one button laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421591/prevent-multiple-submitting-in-one-button-laravel)

Comment: I do disable the button with JS, but they somehow manage to go around it. I need a server-side check.

Comment: Does [rate limiting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting) help? Sidenote: If they bypass the disabled button it might mean they are bots which (most of the time) can be "blocked" with [`robots.txt`](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt)

Comment: Take a look at the awnser actually provided in the link. Or take a look at the awnser of Digvijay. Or maybe it might be easy to actually show your code?

Comment: Yea, rate limiting should work, but I never used it. My route is `Route::post('/affiliate/enter', 'AffiliateController@update')->name('aff_enter');`
How do I limit the rate ONLY for this route?

Comment: ```Route::middleware('throttle:60,1')->post('/affiliate/enter', 'AffiliateController@update')->name('aff_enter');``` See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#rate-limiting

Comment: Also search for "post form honeypot" to trick malicious bots.

Answer (score 1):

## csrf tokens

Laravel makes it easy to protect your application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. Cross-site request forgeries are a type of malicious exploit whereby unauthorized commands are performed on behalf of an authenticated user.

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

The **VerifyCsrfToken middleware**, which is included in the web middleware group, will **automatically verify that the token** in the request input matches the token stored in the session.

Comment: I do have @csrf in my code, but it doesn't seem to help. I'm looking for something more like a server side check within the controller.